# Impossible to delete in Django Admin — object refers to ITSELF as a protected object

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin, mutual-recursion

In Django Admin, I have a model called **Modules**.

When I try to delete a Module object, I get the following error:

```
Deleting the module 'FR menu' would require deleting
the following protected related objects:

Module: FR menu
```

I understand why this would happen if the protected object had been a different model, but in this case, **the warning refers to itself**.

I don't even know where to begin to debug... perhaps it's because of an old migration?
.
This model is a ForeignKey model for a model **called Prefix** this one — here is the **Module model declaration**:

```
positions = ('absolute', 'floating', 'none',)
corners = ('top left', 'top right', 'bottom left', 'bottom right',)

class Module(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='active',)
    display_order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='display order')
    sort1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', verbose_name='main category', blank=True,)
    sort2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', verbose_name='sub category', blank=True,)
    css_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', verbose_name='object ID', blank=True,)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, verbose_name='SVG file (optional)',)
    notes = RichTextField(default='')

    cache_reset   = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='delete cache (or visit example.com/c)',)

    position = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='absolute', choices=Choices(*positions), verbose_name='placement')
    corner = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='top left', choices=Choices(*corners), verbose_name='relative to')
    horz_offset = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='horizontal offset (px)',)
    vert_offset = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='vertical offset (px)',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-active', 'display_order', 'name', 'sort1', 'sort2',]
        verbose_name_plural = "2.2 · Modules"

class ModuleScripts(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', choices=Choices(*script_types), verbose_name='type')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=50000, default='', verbose_name='content',)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='load order')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='active',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "extra script"
        verbose_name_plural = "extra scripts"
        ordering = ["order"]
```

And here is the **Prefix model declaration** that includes Modules as a ForeignKey:

```
class Prefix(models.Model):
    display_order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='display order')
    path = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='', verbose_name='code',)
    default = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', verbose_name='default page')
    responsive = models.ForeignKey(Responsive, default=0, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='screen',)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, default=0, on_delete=models.PROTECT, )
    module = models.ManyToManyField(Module, through='PrefixModules')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.path
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Combination Code"
        verbose_name_plural = "1.4 · Combination Codes"
        ordering = ['display_order']

class PrefixModules(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    prefix = models.ForeignKey(Prefix, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    zindex = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='z index')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='active',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.module.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "module"
        verbose_name_plural = "modules"
        ordering = ["zindex"]
```

Comment: `Module` seems to refer to `PrefixModules` based on its `verbose_name`, so that error most probably refers to the requirement to delete `PrefixModules` first before `Module`, as the foreign key is declared as `module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.PROTECT)`

Comment: Yes that was definitely it. Part of it was just me being tired, because I thought I had checked that the modules I was deleting were not used by prefixes. But mainly I need to change the name so that the message isn't so useless. Thanks so much. If you want some points, write your comment as an answer and I'll choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Module` seems to refer to `PrefixModules` based on its `verbose_name`, so that error most probably refers to the requirement to delete `PrefixModules` first before `Module`, as the foreign key is declared as `module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.PROTECT)`

Answer (score 0):

This issue taught me **the importance of naming your models correctly**.

The problem arose because I used the same name for the model as ForeignKey and the root model.

As a result, the "would require deleting the following protected related objects" message seemed to be referring to itself, when what it was really saying was:

```
Deleting the ROOT MODEL module 'FR menu' would require deleting
the following protected related objects:

Module FOREIGNKEY USED BY PREFIX: FR menu
```

The long-term solution is to **avoid ambiguous model names** and **multiple uses of the same name**.